# Clear app data in ANDROID

Tags: android, database, sqlite

How come whenever I clear my app data, my previously working `SQLite` database doesn't work anymore?
here is my code for my database:

```
package tsu.ccs.capstone;

import android.content.ContentValues;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.database.Cursor;  
import android.database.SQLException;  
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;  
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;  
import android.util.Log;  

public class DBUser {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";  
public static String KEY_USERNAME= "username";  
public static String KEY_PASSWORD = "password"; 
public static String KEY_NUMBER = "number";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";  

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "usersdb";  
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "users";  
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =  
    "create table users (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "  
    + "username text not null, "
    + "password text not null, "
    + "number text not null);";  

private Context context = null;  
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;  
private SQLiteDatabase db;  

public DBUser(Context ctx)  
{  
    this.context = ctx;  
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);  
}  

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper  
{  
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)  
    {  
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
    }  

    //creating the DB
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  
    {  
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)  
    {  
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion  
                + " to "  
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");  
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");  
        onCreate(db);  
    }  
}      

//open DB for writing/reading mode
public void open() throws SQLException  
{  
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();  
}  

//close the DB
public void close()  
{  
    DBHelper.close();  
}      

//insert Initial Values to the DB
public long AddUser()  
{  
     ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();  
     initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, "admin");  
     initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, "admin");  
     return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}  

//delete the entire rows
public long DeleteUser()  
{  
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, "1", null);
} 

public boolean CheckContent()  
{  
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE _id=1", null);  
    if (mCursor != null) {  
        if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)  
        {  
            return true;  
        } 
    }  
 return false;
} 

//update the DB
public boolean UpdateUser(long rowId, String username, String password)  
{  
     ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();  
     newCon.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);  
     newCon.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);  
     return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newCon, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;   
} 

// searching the DB for username and password match
public boolean Login(String username, String password) throws SQLException  
{  
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE username=? AND password=?", new String[]{username,password});  
    if (mCursor != null) {  
        if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)  
        {  
            return true;  
        } 
    }  
 return true;  
}

//Store Recipient's Number to the DB
public boolean EditNumber(long rowId, String number)  
{  
     ContentValues editNumber = new ContentValues();
     editNumber.put(KEY_NUMBER, number);
     return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, editNumber, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;

} 

public Cursor newNumber() {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE _id=1";
    System.out.println(query);
     Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, null);
     cur.moveToFirst();
     return cur;

   }

}
```

and here is my FirstActivity:

```
package tsu.ccs.capstone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

final String PREFS_NAME = "FirstTimeCheker";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    overridePendingTransition (R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);

    DBUser dbUser = new DBUser(FirstActivity.this);  
    dbUser.open();

    if(dbUser.CheckContent()){
        //do nothing
    } else {
        dbUser.AddUser();
    }
    dbUser.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_first, menu);
    return true;
}

public void gotoLogin (View v) {        
    SharedPreferences mPrefs;
    mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // second argument is the default to use if the preference can't be found
    Boolean RegisterScreenShown = mPrefs.getBoolean(PREFS_NAME, false);

    if (!RegisterScreenShown) {
        Intent intentIntro = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentIntro);
        overridePendingTransition (R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREFS_NAME, true);
        editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference
    }else{
        Intent intentAlecc = new Intent(this, AleccActivity.class);
        startActivity(intentAlecc);
        overridePendingTransition (R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);
    }
}

public void gotoCctv (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CctvActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition (R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);
}

public void editUser (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditUserActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition (R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  super.onBackPressed();
  overridePendingTransition (R.anim.incoming, R.anim.outgoing);
}
}
```

Comment: i think when ur clear the app data then all internal memory of app will be clear ..

Comment: yes. thats quite right. but when I run my app after clearing the app data, it seems that the my DB Table doesn't exists/created. I wonder why

Comment: Clear app data will also clear the database that the app created. The database is essentially  a piece of data, after all.

Comment: Your `onCreate` method should be called in that case. Is it?

Comment: What error you are getting in that case? post the logcat.

Comment: @BomberMan Im using my device as my tester, do android phones have LogCat somewhere?
@LawrenceChoy ok. thanks!
@CL. `onCreate` method from my database class? I've tried it. It doesn't work sadly.

Comment: @ShiningCopper if your device is connected to PC then there you can select the device from DDMS and see the logcat in eclipse.

Comment: @BomberMan how can I select it?
I already enable USB Debugging mode. but I can't see my device in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Database is the part of data of your application. Your database doesn't work anymore because it doesn't exist anymore. It is deleted with all the resp app data. Each SQLite database of your app is represented as a single file, and this database file is deleted when you clear the app data.

I [this blog post](http://android-by-example.blogspot.com/2012/12/developing-notepad-application-part-1.html) you can find where is the database file located and how to work with it. You can browse the file system on the device and locate it there.

Put the debug point inside onCreate() method of SQLiteOpenHelper and see if it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it out but you seem to have a DBUser class which incorporates the private DatabaseHelper class.

When the DB doesn't exists, Android automatically calls the onCreate method but I assume it is hidden in your case. Try to move the DatabaseHelper outside the DBUser class.